# Error in SQL query in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: sql, vb.net, visual-studio-2012, sql-server-2008-r2

I am trying my hand at writing something that can be used at work and am learning on my own. I've run into an issue that I cannot find a solution to, although it's very possible that I am just unfamiliar with the right terminology.

I have attached a Visual Studio project to a SQL database and am trying to perform a search where I can enter information in any of the three text boxes and it will filter the returned results accordingly.  Here is the  User search query:

```
SELECT        First_Name AS [First Name], Middle_Name AS [Middle Name], Last_Name AS [Last Name], Users_ID AS [Unique ID]
FROM            Users
WHERE        (First_Name LIKE '%' + @firstName + '%') AND (Last_Name LIKE '%' + @lastName + '%') AND (Users_ID LIKE '%' + @uniqueID + '%')
ORDER BY [Last Name]
```

Here is the SUB I am using to call the search.  The only one I am having an issue with is the User search.

```
Private Sub searchButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles searchButton.Click
    'Clear all variables when the search button is clicked.  This allows Search to start with a clean'
    'slate and gather new or changed variables again.'
    addRemoveValue = Nothing
    jobTitle = Nothing
    jtLocation = Nothing
    jtDepartment = Nothing
    loc = Nothing
    lComments = Nothing
    department = Nothing
    fname = Nothing
    lname = Nothing
    uID = Nothing

    'Gather variables.'
    addRemoveValue = TryCast(addRemoveComboBox.SelectedItem, String)
    jobTitle = TryCast(jobTitleTextBox.Text, String)
    jtLocation = TryCast(jtLocationComboBox.Text, String)
    jtDepartment = TryCast(jtDepartmentComboBox.Text, String)
    loc = TryCast(locationTextBox.Text, String)
    lComments = TryCast(lCommentsTextBox.Text, String)
    department = TryCast(departmentTextBox.Text, String)
    fname = TryCast(firstNameTextBox.Text, String)
    lname = TryCast(lastNameTextBox.Text, String)
    uID = TryCast(uniqueIDTextBox.Text, String)

    'I added this in order to troubleshoot the search feature for the Users search.'
    'If uID = Nothing Then'
    '    uID = "%"'
    'End If'

    'Change the visible buttons in the event of a Search.'
    disableButton.Visible = True
    addButton.Visible = False

    'Populate the Data Grid based on the item the user selects.'
    If addRemoveValue = "Job Title" Then
        With Me.DataGridView1
            .AutoGenerateColumns = True
            .DataSource = RoleTableAdapter.GetDataByTitle(jobTitle, jtLocation, jtDepartment)
            .AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.DisplayedCellsExceptHeaders
            .AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.DisplayedCells
            .BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D
            .EditMode = DataGridViewEditMode.EditOnEnter
        End With
    End If

    If addRemoveValue = "Location" Then
        With Me.DataGridView1
            .AutoGenerateColumns = True
            .DataSource = LocationTableAdapter.GetDataByLoc(loc)
            .AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.DisplayedCellsExceptHeaders
            .AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.DisplayedCells
            .BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D
            .EditMode = DataGridViewEditMode.EditOnEnter
        End With
    End If

    If addRemoveValue = "Department" Then
        With Me.DataGridView1
            .AutoGenerateColumns = True
            .DataSource = DepartmentTableAdapter.GetDataByDept(department)
            .AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.DisplayedCellsExceptHeaders
            .AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.DisplayedCells
            .BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D
            .EditMode = DataGridViewEditMode.EditOnEnter
        End With
    End If

    If addRemoveValue = "User" Then
        With Me.DataGridView1
            .AutoGenerateColumns = True
            .DataSource = UsersTableAdapter.GetDataByName(uID, fname, lname)
            .AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.DisplayedCellsExceptHeaders
            .AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.DisplayedCells
            .BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D
            .EditMode = DataGridViewEditMode.EditOnEnter
            .Columns("Unique ID").DisplayIndex = 0
            .Columns("Last Name").DisplayIndex = 1
            .Columns("First Name").DisplayIndex = 2
            .Columns("Middle Name").DisplayIndex = 3
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

Whenever I test this, I receive the following error:

> Failed to enable constraints. One or more rows contain values
>   violating non-null, unique, or foreign-key constraints.

I have looked at the properties of all of the columns and all of them can contain NULL values. I have looked and made sure there are no foreign-key contraints on any of my tables. I am stumped as to what to look for next in order to resolve this as the other three searches I have in this code work just fine and they have very similar queries.

Any help you can provide would be awesome!  Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Are there scenarios where firstname, lastname, and/or userid might be blank?

Also sometimes this error pops up if you change a column length in the DB but don't update the dataset.

Comment: yes, there are.  My goal is that users will be able to search using one or more fields, but not have to use all of them.

Comment: What datatype is your @uniqueID coming through as?  I know it's string in the part I can see, but if it's getting converted to int before it's applied, then that can be problematic, though I would expect a different error.  Otherwise, make sure any binding isn't resulting in uniqueID duplicating or being null, if it is in fact constrained as unique (because afaik, a unique constraint without not null will allow null, but only ONE null)

Comment: The datatype for @uniqueID is varchar(12). it was set as such because occasionally the ID will have a letter in it.

It does happen to be the primary key for the table I am using, but I am just selecting rows, not adding rows, so it seems logical that the unique property wouldn't come into play as all of the contents of that column are already unique in the database.

Am I off-base on that?

Comment: Well, sorta.  There can be a couple of sources of wonkiness that you aren't expecting.  First off, the dataset (make sure you didn't change the size of anything and not refresh it) can have its own ideas of what's allowed and what isn't.  Second, if you're using binding, the controls can also have ideas of what's allowed and what isn't.  I guess at this point, I would try the following:  1) copy-paste your select into your server's query space (you will need to define the variables) and see if it works there, 2) remove the where clauses and add them back one by one to see what's wrong.